# SystemD service with an ExecStartPre=git pull

Tags: git, systemd, debian-jessie

How can I `cd /path/to/repo && git pull` in the `ExecStartPre` section of a systemd service?

Comment: Whats your question? (if you are wondering about the `&&`, just wrap your commands in a shell, e.g.: `ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "command1 && command2"`)

Comment: Oh nice, I think that would have worked too! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.. I also figured out how to use RVM to do some rails(y) things too:

```
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/repo

ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/git pull
ExecStartPre=/home/rails/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.3.1 do bundle install
ExecStartPre=/home/rails/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1/rake assets:precompile
```